# How to display a UK date on a HTML Form, then save it in a standard format to the database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm building a web app and the customer has requested that any date field that must have data entered in to it be in the UK format (DD/MM/YYYY). Currently, I have it so that all the date fields must have a date entered in the YYYY/MM/DD format because this is what the database uses.

How can I let a user enter a date in the UK format, but then flip it around to then save it correctly to the database?

Answer (score 0):

In `beforeSave` callback check if a date field is provided and if so, use [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create a `DateTime` object from your display format. And then change it to sql format via [DateTime::format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['date_field'])) {
    $this->data[$this->alias]['date_field'] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->data[$this->alias]['date_field'])->format('Y/m/d');
}
```